# Genymotion access to local web server

Tags: android, proxy, localhost, virtualbox

I have installed **Genymotion 2.2** with Android 4.1 guest OS. Also, I have **Apache** running on host OS with several local sites.

Is it possible to get each local site from the guest's Android browser?

I tried to do this with **ProxyDroid** app, but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. As you can see in the image below, I am connecting to my Tomcat server running on my laptop via the browser in Genymotion machine. Notice that I have used my IP address to connect to Tomcat:

[image]

Comment: Well, this is not exactly what i need, i'll try to explain: of course i can type host's ip adress, but what i get is default apache website (first directory in httpd_vhosts.conf). I want to get it by name - in host OS (Win7) i have custom hosts file in which that names are written. For examle, in other guest OS (WinXP) i can set up proxy in browser to HostIP:80 then type "site1.local" and this will work.